# gitlab-ci job runs when tag pushed regardless of changes

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm having a really annoying issue where I'm trying to have a job run when either tag is pushed AND changes in the directory occur.

```
semver_tag:
  stage: semver_tag
  image: mkver:1.0
  script:
    - TAG=$(git mkver next)
    - echo "Next tag is $TAG..."
    - git mkver tag
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG == "staging" || $CI_COMMIT_TAG == "production"
      changes:
        - src/*
      when: always
    - when: never
```

How can I make it evaluate the OR and the change?

Answer (score 0):

After trawling through the docs I find this:

> The changes rule always evaluates to true when pushing a new branch or a new tag to GitLab.

So, I guess this is just not possible when using tags!

Answer (score 0):

If you usually tag your branches from the Gitlab web front-end, you are pretty sure that there are no changes in the files in tag events; so you can avoid the job in tag events and make Gitlab trigger the job just when the files are changed in push events:

```
only:
    changes:
      - src/**/*
except:
  - tags
```

But I couldn't find a way to make GitLab Pipeline check the actual changes on the `branches` events.